# Lightning JS Chart causing crashes and not showing data correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lightningchart

I have a component that I want to show a graph with multiple line series representing price changes over the last 24 hours. I have an endpoint that sends this data and I use the code below to show it.

One of the issues comes from errors seeming to come from the library itself meaning the graph will not even show up. [Errors from the console when I load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwcz7.png).

Other times, the page will load for a second and then go white and drain enough CPU to cause a crash.

The few times that the graph actually shows up on screen, it does not show any lines until the lines 81-85 are uncommented which it then shows the lines but does not zoom in on them leaving a mess on the screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-magic-numbers */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { LegendBoxBuilders, lightningChart, Themes } from "@arction/lcjs";
import "./TopCurrencyGraph.css";
import axios from "axios";
export interface data {
  data: dataPoint[];
}

export interface dataPoint {
  currency: string;
  percentage: number;
  timestamp: string;
}

interface graphPoint {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const TopCurrencyGraph = () => {
  const historicalAddr = `http://${
    process.env.back || "localhost:8000"
  }/historical24hChangeData`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const map: { [name: string]: graphPoint[] } = {};
    axios
      .get(historicalAddr)
      .then((res) => {
        const { points } = res.data;
        const pointList = points as dataPoint[];
        pointList.forEach((obj) => {
          const newPoint = {
            x: new Date(obj.timestamp).getTime() * (60 * 24),
            y: obj.percentage * 100,
          };
          if (obj.currency in map) {
            map[obj.currency].push(newPoint);
          } else {
            map[obj.currency] = [newPoint];
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, historicalAddr);
      });
    const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
      theme: Themes.lightNew,
      container: "currency-graph",
    });
    chart.setTitle("Top Currencies");
    chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTitle("Time");
    chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTitle("Percentage Change");

    const entries = Object.entries(map);
    const names = entries.map(([a, _b]) => a);
    const lists = entries.map(([_, b]) => b);

    const seriesArray = new Array(5).fill(null).map((_, idx) =>
      chart
        .addLineSeries({
          dataPattern: {
            pattern: "ProgressiveX",
          },
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line arrow-parens
        .setStrokeStyle((stroke) => stroke.setThickness(1))
        .setName(names[idx])
    );

    seriesArray.forEach((series, idx) => {
      if (idx === 1) {
        series.add(lists[idx]);
      }
    });

    chart.addLegendBox(LegendBoxBuilders.HorizontalLegendBox).add(chart);

    return () => {
      chart.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  // done thnx
  return (
    <div className="graph-container">
      <div id="currency-graph" className="graph-container"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopCurrencyGraph;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks syntax wise correct, but I believe you are running into issues due to not managing asynchronous code (axios getting data from your endpoint) properly.

```
const map: { [name: string]: graphPoint[] } = {};
axios
   .get(historicalAddr)
   .then((res) => {
      // This code is NOT executed immediately, but only after some time later.
      ...
   })

// This code and everything below is executed BEFORE the code inside `then` block.
// Because of this, you end up supplying `undefined` or other incorrect values to series / charts which shows as errors.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
   theme: Themes.lightNew,
   container: "currency-graph",
});
```

You might find it useful to debug the values you supply to series, for example like below. I think the values are not what you would expect.

```
seriesArray.forEach((series, idx) => {
   if (idx === 1) {
      console.log('series.add', lists[idx])
      series.add(lists[idx]);
   }
});
```

**Improvement suggestion**

Here's my attempt at modifying the code you supplied to manage the asynchronous data loading correctly, by moving all code that relies on the data after the data is processed.

```
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-magic-numbers */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { LegendBoxBuilders, lightningChart, Themes } from "@arction/lcjs";
import "./TopCurrencyGraph.css";
import axios from "axios";
export interface data {
  data: dataPoint[];
}

export interface dataPoint {
  currency: string;
  percentage: number;
  timestamp: string;
}

interface graphPoint {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const TopCurrencyGraph = () => {
  const historicalAddr = `http://${
    process.env.back || "localhost:8000"
  }/historical24hChangeData`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
      theme: Themes.lightNew,
      container: "currency-graph",
    });
    chart.setTitle("Top Currencies");
    chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTitle("Time");
    chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTitle("Percentage Change");

    const seriesArray = new Array(5).fill(null).map((_, idx) =>
      chart
        .addLineSeries({
          dataPattern: {
            pattern: "ProgressiveX",
          },
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line arrow-parens
        .setStrokeStyle((stroke) => stroke.setThickness(1))
    );

    chart.addLegendBox(LegendBoxBuilders.HorizontalLegendBox).add(chart);

    axios
      .get(historicalAddr)
      .then((res) => {
        const { points } = res.data;
        const pointList = points as dataPoint[];
        const map: { [name: string]: graphPoint[] } = {};
        pointList.forEach((obj) => {
          const newPoint = {
            x: new Date(obj.timestamp).getTime() * (60 * 24),
            y: obj.percentage * 100,
          };
          if (obj.currency in map) {
            map[obj.currency].push(newPoint);
          } else {
            map[obj.currency] = [newPoint];
          }
        });

        const entries = Object.entries(map);
        const names = entries.map(([a, _b]) => a);
        const lists = entries.map(([_, b]) => b);

        seriesArray.forEach((series, idx) => {
          series.setName(names[idx])
          if (idx === 1) {
            series.add(lists[idx]);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, historicalAddr);
      });

    return () => {
      chart.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  // done thnx
  return (
    <div className="graph-container">
      <div id="currency-graph" className="graph-container"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopCurrencyGraph;
```